# RME Fireface UFX II: connecting unbalanced cable to balanced jack?

Tags: audio-recording, cable

Not sure if anyone out there has any RME products, but thought I'd ask...in the RME Fireface UFX II manual it states (on p. 38):

> When using unbalanced cables with TRS jacks: be sure to connect the 'ring' contact of the TRS jack to ground.  Otherwise noise may occur, caused by the unconnected negative input of the balanced input.

What does it mean here specifically when they say "connect the 'ring' contact of the TRS jack to ground"? Does it mean pushing it in all the way? Or something else?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the internal wiring of the TRS jack. The extra ring conductor needs to be connected to ground (just like the sleeve), effectively turning the TRS jack into a regular TS jack.

The input of the RME Fireface expects a TRS jack to be carrying a balanced signal, with the tip and ring signals out of phase. According to the docs, having the ring "floating" with no signal (and not grounded) can create noise in the interface.

The easiest solution here is to not use TRS cables. Instead, use regular TS cables to carry the unbalanced signals.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought that TRS jacks referred to the input on the Fireface itself, not the jack at the end of the cable.